# Xamarin WebView getting messages from websource

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview

We are implementing Apple Pay/Google Play in our existing app. Our payment processor only supports hosted payments (e.g. webpage). We plan on hosting an iFrame as the source in the WebView.

How can we receive messages from the iFrame? For example, when the user completes the Apple Pay part, how can the iFrame notify the WebView? We were trying to use window.external.notify (in the iFrame) to send a message with a payload. Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems you should use the js to connect the iframe and the webview.

Comment: Any pointers to how?

Comment: I'm not good at JS and H5, but the webview support JS.